# Como extrair uma palavra de uma string (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Eu estou com um problema no meu script.

Contexto: Estou precisando retirar uma informação de uma string que está na coluna nm_conteudo, porem todos as funções que eu tento não estão dando certo. Tentei fazer separadamente e funciona apenas com uma linha, quando adiciono uma coluna, dá erro. Segue o comando que eu tentei

```
select top(1000) nm_retorno as teste
CASE WHEN nm_retorno LIKE '% id_revenda %'
                THEN SUBSTRING(nm_retorno, (len(nm_retorno) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE('id_revenda'), REVERSE(nm_retorno)) + 12), len(nm_retorno))
                ELSE nm_retorno
           END as TesteRevenda
from Tabela
```

Tentei algumas outras formas mas foi sem sucesso. O erro que aparece é

> mensagem 156, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 2
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Tentei também o seguinte script e deu erro

```
select top(1000) CASE WHEN nm_retorno LIKE '% ID_REVENDA=" %'
                THEN SUBSTRING(nm_retorno, (len(nm_retorno) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE('ID_REVENDA="'), REVERSE(nm_retorno)) + 12), len(nm_retorno))
                ELSE nm_retorno
           END as TesteRevenda
from Tabela
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem 8116, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1 Argument data type text is
> invalid for argument 1 of len function.

Grato desde já!

Comment: No seu primeiro comando não está faltando uma `,` antes do CASE?

Comment: Mesmo com a virgula o erro persiste

Comment: O erro de sintaxe? Aliás é MySQL ou SQL Server?

Comment: É SQL Server mesmo

Comment: Se minha resposta te ajudou, por favor, escolha com a resposta para que nós possamos ajudar os outros também! Dei um Up aqui pra vc;

Answer (score 0):

Além da virgula que está faltando.

Para pegar o tamanho do texto em uma coluna do tipo `text` você precisa usar a função `DATALENGTH(<nome_da_coluna_tipo_texto>)`

Por isso que é importante você compartilhar o script do seu banco... Assim podemos ver como foi construída a tabela.

Esse erro abaixo acontece porque você está usando uma coluna do tipo `text` que a função `len()` não suporta.

> Mensagem 8116, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1 Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function. – Lucas Rossini 10 horas atrás

Então você precisa usar `DATALENGTH()` que resolve:

A função `DATALENGTH()` retorna o número de bytes então precisa dividir o valor por 2 para chegar o tamanho de carácteres;

```sql
SELECT top 10
    AddressLine1 AS Rua,
    DATALENGTH(AddressLine1)/2 AS TamanhoTexto,
    CASE WHEN AddressLine1 LIKE '% Napa %'
         THEN SUBSTRING(AddressLine1, CHARINDEX('Napa', AddressLine1), len('Napa') )
         ELSE 'Não tem'
    END as ResultadoCase
FROM Person.Address
order by AddressID;
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Eu criando uma tabela nova no Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18. Rodei o script que vc enviou funcionando no SQL Server e deu o erro a seguir

Mensagem 8116, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1 Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function.

Comment: Reformulei a resposta da uma olhada

Answer (score 0):

CASE
WHEN FUNCAORM LIKE '% JUNIOR%' THEN SUBSTRING(FUNCAORM, 1, PATINDEX('% JUNIOR%', FUNCAORM)-1 )
WHEN FUNCAORM LIKE '% PLENO%' THEN SUBSTRING(FUNCAORM, 1, PATINDEX('% PLENO%', FUNCAORM)-1 )
WHEN FUNCAORM LIKE '% SENIOR%' THEN SUBSTRING(FUNCAORM, 1, PATINDEX('% SENIOR%', FUNCAORM)-1 )
ELSE FUNCAORM
END AS FUNCAO_AJUSTADA,

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).